# How to delete windows file with owner dot-dot-dot

Tags: windows, codeblocks

Frequently, after doing a "rebuild workspace" in codeblocks ( which deletes all target executable and .obj files ) one of the executables remains.  ( this may well happen because the executable was still running - in which case I stop the executable running and attempt to delete it from the command line. )  I cannot proceed until this file is deleted.  When I attempt to delete the file, I am told that I need admin privileges.  However, running cmd.exe as administrator still refuses to delete the files.

The only way I have found to remove the file is to reboot.  After a reboot the file has gone.  Is there a simpler way to remove the file?

Looking at the file, the owner has been changed to "..."

```
C:\Users\James\code\TeleIMRI\bin>dir /Q *.exe
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is 5043-2553

 Directory of C:\Users\James\code\TeleIMRI\bin

08/18/2017  11:53 AM         8,998,912 DESKTOP-5Q225AK\James  Pelex3DGraph.exe
08/18/2017  11:51 AM         8,199,680 DESKTOP-5Q225AK\James  PelexDataGraph.exe
08/10/2017  02:23 PM         9,480,192 ...                    PelexMixerGUI.exe
07/26/2017  01:05 PM         1,866,752 DESKTOP-5Q225AK\James  PelexNoter.exe
08/18/2017  11:54 AM         2,483,200 DESKTOP-5Q225AK\James  PelexPulser.exe
```

PelexMixerGUI is the file I cannot delete

[image]

The takeown command does not work either.

Tried:

```
C:\Users\James\code\TeleIMRI\bin>icacls PelexMixerGUI.exe /grant Administrators:F
PelexMixerGUI.exe: Access is denied.
Successfully processed 0 files; Failed processing 1 files

C:\Users\James\code\TeleIMRI\bin>del PelexMixerGUI.exe
C:\Users\James\code\TeleIMRI\bin\PelexMixerGUI.exe
Access is denied.
```

Comment: I don't have experience with codeblocks, but are you sure the process is terminated before attempting to delete it?  Look through the task manager details to make sure.

Comment: It is plausible that the process is still running when codeblocks attempts to delete the executable.  I stop the process, then attempt to delete it as described in my question.

Comment: At CMD, you could try:  takeown /F pelexmixer.gui.exe  See what happens.

Comment: The takeown command does not work either.

Comment: after performing takeown, try this, and attempt to delete after:  icacls PelexMixerGUI.exe /grant Administrators:F

Comment: Tried.  Failed.  See question for details